# Azure_superuser account password for Postgresql database on Azure

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-database-postgresql

I have provisioned Azure Database for Postgresql, I'm trying to execute copy command in c# Azure function to load data from csv file to the database.

It throws an error saying ERROR: must be superuser to COPY to or from a file

The question is how do I use the user Azure_superuser, where do I get password for this account. This account is automatically created while setting up the PostgreSQL on Azure.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is a PaaS service, you will not have access to the Super User account.  You will have access to the Admin account:[Azure PostgreSQL Server Admin Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-create-users#the-server-admin-account)